# css button editing issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to edit the css button, and in that css button, I had to add a qty field with plus and minus buttons to make it more dynamic

Right now the button is like this

http://prntscr.com/cza7s0

I have the css like this:

```
   .thumbnail input.productcart_btn {
        border: none;
        background: #f25c27 url(../img/prodcutcart.png) right 7px no-repeat;
        color: #fff;
        float: right;
        padding: 8px 27px 8px 8px;
        font-size: 13px;
}
```

and html like this

```
<input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="productcart_btn">
```

ready to modify the text to something relevant like `Add` or `Cart` so the `qty` **select box** and *plus* and *minus* button can fit inside it

I gave it a try somewhat but not sure it will work in responsive mode or not

https://jsfiddle.net/vnk17uoe/

Comment: You will want to use a `button` element instead of an `input type="submit"` since a `button` can have content, which an `input type="submit"` cannot have.

Comment: i can change it but how do i fit the qty select inside this button with plus and minus buttons

Comment: Use submit button with Add to cart and create drop downlist and +/- buttons separate from Submit button. Keep things simple.

Comment: correct, but sometime there is a need to do like this, in that case????